# Running MariaDB instead of Postgresql on Fusionauth Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, mariadb, fusionauth

first of all I'm really sorry for my english. I started to build a fusionauth application on my Windows PC a few days ago. For this project I used a MariaDB. Now I buyed a vServer and my plan is to run Fusionauth with the help of docker.

After installing everything and following this tutorial: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/docker

I had to change the .env file. But here you can only set a Username and Password for POSTGRES...
Don't really know what to do, because MariaDB should work with Fusionauth.

```html
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Would be grateful for every help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB is no longer fully compatible with MySQL. Therefore, FusionAuth does not officially support MariaDB due to the fact that we are using modern MySQL functions and SQL. However, if you manage to get MariaDB working, post your solution to our forums (https://fusionauth.io/community/forum/) to let the community know.

We recommend using PostgreSQL for FusionAuth if possible, but MySQL also works. If you are going to use MySQL, you'll need to modify the Docker Compose file to use the MySQL Docker container instead of PostgreSQL.

The MySQL Docker container is documented here: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Once you have MySQL running, you'll configure FusionAuth to connect to it using the environment variables that are documented here: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/reference/configuration